# Nested objects in form not validating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-attributes, simple-form

I have a nested form where users can book appointments. However, I've noticed an issue with the form where a user can fill out the required `Client` model fields and not the required `Appointment` model fields and the form still submits since for some reason the validation on the `Appointment` model isn't being triggered. The only time the `Appointment` validation is triggered is when the associated form fields are populated. How do I get the nested form to verify that the `Appointment` fields are being filled out? Since clients can have multi

Customer model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :appointments_attributes

  validates_presence_of :name, :email

  validates :email, :format => {:with => /^[^@][\w.-]+@[\w.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}$/i}
  validates :email, :uniqueness => true
end
```

Appointment model:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer

  attr_accessible :date

  validates_presence_of :date
end
```

Customers controller:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
    @appointment = @customer.appointments.build
  end

  def create
    @customer = Customer.find_or_initialize_by_email(params[:customer])
    if @customer.save
      redirect_to success_customers_path
    else
      # Throw error
      @appointment = @customer.appointments.select{ |appointment| appointment.new_record? }.first
      render :new
    end
  end

  def success
  end
end
```

Customers form view:

```
= simple_form_for @customer, :url => customers_path, :method => :post, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" } do |customer_form|
  = customer_form.input :name
  = customer_form.input :email
  = customer_form.simple_fields_for :appointments, @appointment do |appointment_form|
    = appointment_form.input :date
```

UPDATE: Providing routes

```
resources :customers, :only => [:new, :create] do
  get :success, :on => :collection
end
```

Comment: So if nothing in the appointment nested form is filled out, you want that appointment to still validate?

Comment: Correct, it's a single form which populates both models so I want all the required fields (from both models) to validate. All the fields have an asterisks to denote that they are required but if a user only fills out the name and email fields the appointment date field isn't validated to make sure a value is entered. They are able to submit the form and get redirected to the success page (which is not the behavior I want).

Answer (score 0):

If a customer has to have an appointment:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :appointments
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments

   attr_accessible :name, :email, :appointments_attributes

   validates_presence_of :name, :email, :appointment # <- add your appointment
   ....
end
```

This will require each customer has at least one appointment.

**EDIT based on comment**

Instead of using build in your controller, I think you can use `create` instead which will then associate that appointment with the customer and force validation.

Customers controller:

```
def edit
    @customer = Customer.find_or_initialize_by_email(params[:customer])
    @appointment = @customer.appointments.create
end
```

And you'd do the same in your `new` method

Comment: True, it will require each customer to have at least one appointment. But if a returning customer (email addresses are unique so I know when it's a returning customer) fills out the form again, I get the same behavior where if they don't fill in the appointment fields, the form doesn't validate that the appointment fields are entered.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to pass an ID for the customer. There isn't a registration process to the form (as per business requirements out of my hands). I know they are new or returning customers by the `find_or_initialize_by_email` method in the controller.

Comment: That part wasn't really the point, but I updated it. Does the @customer.appointments.create do what you need?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow your example. At what point is the `:customer` param supposed to be set? I tried using the same code from your example in my `new` method and I got an error: `You cannot call create unless the parent is saved`. I'm hoping that I do not have to create a second page for an `edit` method.

Comment: Your edit and new functions probably do need to be separated, or you'll need to include a bunch of if/else statements. You'll notice scaffolding in rails creates new and edit methods with views, but they share the same form. I would take the same approach. For your `new` method use `build`, since the `validates_presence_of` will capture that, and `create` in your `edit`